# Possible to enumerate or access module-level function declarations in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

In Node.js, if I load a module which contains code in module-scope like:

```
this["foo"] = function() { console.log("foo"); }
```

...then I appear to get a globally available function that I can call just by saying `foo()` from any code using the module.  It can be seen as one of the printed items with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)`.

However, if I put the following in module scope instead:

```
function foo() { console.log("foo"); }
```

...then it produces a function which can similarly be called within that module as `foo()`, but is invisible outside of it (e.g. does not show up as one of the items with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)`).

I gather this is a change in runtime behavior from what's done in browsers.  A browser seems to poke everything into global scope by default (and for years people have had to consciously avoid this by wrapping things up in anonymous functions/etc.)

My question is whether NodeJs has some secret way of interacting with these declarations outside of the module in which they are declared **BESIDES using `exports.(...) = (...)`**.  Can they be enumerated somehow, or are they garbage collected as soon as they are declared if they're not called by a module export?  If I knew what the name of such a function was going to be in advance of loading a module...could I tell Node.js to "capture it" when it was defined?

I'm not expecting any such capabilities to be well-documented...but perhaps there's a debugger feature or other system call.  One of the best pointers would be to the specific code in the Node.js project where this kind of declaration is handled, to see if there are any loopholes.

---

*Note: In researching a little into V8 I saw that a "function definition" doesn't get added to the context.  It's put into an "activation object" of the "execution context", and cannot be programmatically accessed.  If you want some "light reading" I found:*

http://coachwei.sys-con.com/node/676031/mobile

http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible in node without more advanced reflection tools like the *debugger*.

The only way to do this would be to use [`__parent__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Parent) which was removed due to security issues and other things (hard to optimize, not standard to begin with) . When you run the script those variables become closed under the module. You can not access them elsewhere without explicitly exporting them.

This is not a bug, it's by design. It's just how node works. [see this closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465423/how-can-i-list-all-the-functions-in-my-node-js-script/15741008#15741008).

If this sort of reflection was available without tools like the debugger it would have been *extremely* hard to optimize the source code (at least the way v8 works) , meaning the answer to your question is no. Sorry.

Comment: Sigh.  This makes life difficult.  It would seem that if you were willing to compromise with some setting or parameter the optimizations could be preserved for people who don't need the feature.  Oh well.

Comment: If this is for a personal project, you're more than welcome to run node.js with v8 flags that let you do pretty much anything like --expose_debug_as and hack at it.

Answer (score 2):

if you fill in exports.foo = foo; at the end of your file it will be available in other files in node, assuming that you do var myFile = require('myFile.js') with the file name and you call the function via myFile.foo(); You can even rename the function for outside use in exports and set whatever you want to call the package when you use require.

BTW you can enumerate these functions just like you do on any JSON object (ie for k in ...)

Comment: Ah, I should have been explicit that I know about exports.  I thought that mentioning the `this["foo"] = function()` case would suggest that I knew there it was possible to make calling modules aware of the existence of the declaration *if one could edit the module file*.  I'm actually trying to see if there's some way to dig into a file without editing it to do explicit exports, especially in the case of a requirer knowing exactly what they might want to catch for an export...